# Storing data best practices question with MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am storing one artist's name ('Pablo Picasso') and the titles of each painting he completed in a MySQL table.

For each title, I want to include the size, medium, year, etc as metadata that describes the painting itself.

**Question:**
How would you recommend storing this data for easy manipulation?

1. Would you create a new row for each painting with the respective metadata?
2. Or would you use one row and use commas to seperate the values of the metadata?

In other words, I'm curious to know any of the mysql best practices for storing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
artists table
-------------
id
first_name
last_name
other_attributes


paintings table
---------------
id
name
artist_id
year
other_attributes
```

Comment: Okay so splitting into two tables and connecting them is the optimal way to store the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely best practices to store data. And the main purpose of Mysql is to have structured data that follows a very simple rule. One column contains one data. So the second option is definitely discouraged.

Depending on the number of attributes that you want to store about a picture the first option seems the solution. If you have a fixed number of metadata. Although if the number of metadata varies still one row for each painting